# MVC3 + WIF - FederationResult missing "wctx"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, claims-based-identity, federated-identity, wif

I have an MVC3 app for which I want to implement claims support.  My goal is as follows:

1. provide a SignIn link, which when clicked displays a popup window with username/password and Facebook/WindowsLive/Google etc. links
2. automatically redirect to my SignIn page when a protected controller is accessed e.g. /Order/Delete

I've set up the application and providers in AppFabricLabs.com and included the STS in my project.  I've also created an implementation of IAuthorizationFilter so I can mark my controllers as [WifAuth] and successfully get the OnAuthorization method called.  I've implemented the use-case where the visitor has not been authenticated like this:

```
    private static void AuthenticateUser(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        var fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
        var signIn = new SignInRequestMessage(new Uri(fam.Issuer), fam.Realm);
        context.Result = new RedirectResult(signIn.WriteQueryString());
    }
```

and successfully get AppFabricLabs page with my Identity Provider choices (haven't figured out how to customise that page).  When I log in my returnUrl gets called so I land in a controller method /Home/FederationResult, however the form posted to me contains only **wa** and **wresult** fields but I need **wctx** to know where to send the user... I haven't been able to figure out why.

the **wresult** is an XML document that contains (amongst a bzillion other things) the name and e-mail address of the user logging in but sadly does not contain the url to which the user was headed.

have I failed to configure something or am I just off base?  thoughts anyone?

- e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify a Context for the `SignInRequestMessage`:

```
signIn.Context = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
```

The `wctx` parameter is included in every request/response and also part of the form posted finally to your site.

Comment: awesome.  `signIn.Context = context.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl` in my case.